# Can I make elasticsearch index like hive's partitioned table?

Tags: elasticsearch, hive

Hive tables can partition Date Field data into keys within a table.

Can I also do the elasticsearch index?

I would like to be able to partition an index by date using specific field values within the index.

I would appreciate it if you have any of these techniques, even if you are not necessarily using partitioning with specific field values.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can  define a index with a `YYYY.MM.dd` format.

[This is what Logstash does, by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index)

In Kibana, you can do wildcard searches on `logstash-*` or `logstash-2018.*`. Not sure if you can do the same with the regular search API